# How can I use the mongo_run_command function to rename a collection of MongoDB in C?

Tags: c, mongodb, collections, rename, mongo-c-driver

I'm trying to rename a collection in a C program but this don't work:

```
commandData = (bson *) malloc(sizeof(bson));
commandOut = (bson *) malloc(sizeof(bson));

int result;

bson_init(commandData);
bson_init(commandOut);
bson_append_string(commandData, "renameCollection", "pru.collecPRU");
bson_append_string(commandData, "to", "pru.collecOK");
bson_append_bool(commandData, "dropTarget", 1);

result = mongo_run_command(conn, "admin", commandData, commandOut);

if(result != MONGO_OK) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s Rename ERROR\n", dateTime);
  bson_destroy(commandOut);
  free(commandOut);
}

bson_destroy(commandData);
free(commandData);
```

Can someone help to me?

Comment: Any error codes? It's not a sharded collection, is it?

Comment: In commandOut returns a 1 but result is not MONGO_OK, and it's not a sharded collection.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the declaration, is an integer:

int result;

Comment: What's the value of `result` when `commandOut` is a `1`? What's the error code?

Comment: The value of result is -1

Comment: Oh, that's very disappointing as it's not a specific error code. Does the exact same `rename` work if you try it from the MongoDB console?

Comment: Yes, in mongo console works fine with that command:

db.pru.collecPRU("collecOK", true)

Comment: I don't find any use example of function: mongo_run_command(), I don't know if I'm doing a bad use of it.

Comment: could you try calling `mongo_cmd_get_prev_error(conn, "admin", &out) where out is a `BSON` object after the error occurs?

Comment: Hi, mongo_cmd_get_prev_error returns 0

Comment: The result is the same passing the db 'pru' or 'admin' to mongo_run_command function, I don't know if I'm doing a bad use of this function, I don't see an specefic one to rename collections.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. The C driver is frustratingly lacking in documentation.

Comment: I think the same, it's frustrating (I read the API to found functions), and I don't found any example of use of this function, even invoquing another command...

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: There are examples/tests in the github repository that do other commands. Just not `renameCollection`.

Comment: Thanks, I will see them.